# How to reduce Outlook 365 Cached Exchange Mode network traffic?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, network-traffic, cached-exchange-mode

Working from home I noticed my Microsoft Outlook 365 Cached Exchange Mode had used ~1TB data last month! (My cable provider sent me a warning reminding me I only have 1.2TB/month!)
I have tried turning down the cache from 6 months to 2 weeks but did not see any reduction in traffic. I also tried removing my account from Outlook and re-initializing to no avail. Turning off the Cached Exchange Mode reduced the traffic to almost nothing, but it becomes a pain to work then. My account holds about 15 GB of data.
Any suggestions on how to reduce traffic?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, to minimize network traffic, The Download headers only  setting might be able to suit you requirements. Please check the follow articles about how to set Download headers only.

[Managing Outlook behavior for slow connections](http://Managing%20Outlook%20behavior%20for%20slow%20connections)

[How to set Outlook to download only E-mail headers](https://www.officetooltips.com/outlook_2016/tips/how_to_set_outlook_to_download_only_e-mail_headers.html)